# How can you loop with IO in intel assembly?

Tags: loops, assembly, io, x86, intel

I'm new to the intel assembly language and trying to learn how to write loops with inputs and outputs. The loop has been working when I try just doing outputs, but then stopped working when I tried to use a user input.

My code:

```
                                //Taking the address of msg1, outputting it and clearing the stack
        lea eax, msg1
        push eax   
        call printf  
        add esp, 4

                                //Taking address of counter and inp_fmt, pushing it onto the stack and then
                                   taking an input to save it to the counter address.
        lea eax, counter
        push eax
        lea eax, inp_fmt
        push eax
        call scanf
        add esp, 8

        mov ecx, counter        //Sets the ecx to the input value counter
        inp_loop:               
            push ecx            //Saving value of the ecx onto the stack
            lea eax, msg2
            push eax
            call printf         //Outputs the enter a number message
            

            lea eax, test1
            push eax
            lea eax, inp_fmt
            push eax
            call scanf          //User inputs a number and stores at in test1
            

            
            pop eax             //gets rid of the eax value at top of stack
            pop ecx             //returns the counter value on the stack to ecx
        
        loop inp_loop
```

This will now loop infinitely, and when I step into the code the value for the ecx has changed from the value set to a random number.

[Screenshot of the value of ecx after the first loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrtyT.png)

Any help with this problem would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I don't think the `pop eax` before `pop ecx` is right - where do you think you pushed this value?

Comment: You're unbalancing the stack.  Keep an eye on the stack pointer register as you debug, and you'll see that the `pop ecx` doesn't pop the right value since the stack has become unbalanced — its not back to having the pushed `ecx` at the top.

Comment: What assembler is this?  A recent version of NASM that accepts `lea eax, inp_fmt` as equivalent to `lea eax, [inp_fmt]` for MASM compatibility?  You should just `push inp_fmt`, it's the same 32-bit immediate.  Not that that matters for your stack balance bug.  Also, use a different register for the loop counter, like ESI or EBX, so you don't have to push/pop it around a `call`.  Like `dec ebx` / `jnz inp_loop`.  That's why the calling convention has call-preserved registers.  (The `loop` instruction is slow, don't use it except for code-size optimization when you don't need push/pop.)